# AZURE : SQL Database : Creating a table from .net code

Tags: c#, azure

Is it possible to create a Azure SQL database table employing code written within Visual Studio?

I have made attempts by creating an API on my mobile service and then calling that but each time I run into permission failures.

If I create the table directly from within Azure then my CRUD code works fine. However I need to provide users with the ability to create tables without them having to access Azure accounts.

Answer (score 1):

I think you should try DbInitializer and Migrations in your .NET backend of Windows Azure Mobile Service.
In the attached link described how it works.
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/writingdata_services/archive/2014/03/28/mobile-services-net-backend-initializers-and-model-updates.aspx